# reformat column based on column name

Tags: r

***The problem:***

I would like to convert columns in my data frame from character to numeric format if the name of the column contains the characters "mmHg" or "cm".

***The input***

```
structure(list(ffgmmHg = c("359", "555", "293", "691", "767", 
"974", "785", "736", "862", "259"), ffgcm = c("73", "378", "524", 
"856", "798", "448", "21", "614", "158", "801"), ffgss = c("A", 
"C", "M", "B", "U", "H", "V", "J", "O", "P")), .Names = c("ffgmmHg", 
"ffgcm", "ffgss"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

***The desired output:***

`ffgmmHg` and `ffgcm` will both be numeric format whereas the column `ffgss` will remain as character.

The attempt:

```
lapply(data, function(x) ifelse(grepl("cm|mmHg",names(x)),as.numeric(as.character(x)),"Nope"))
```

***The error:***

No error, but the output I get is:

```
$ffgmmHg
logical(0)

$ffgcm
logical(0)

$ffgss
logical(0)
```

and the columns have not changed their format

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We need to `grep` on the `names` of the 'data'.  Inside the `lapply`, we get the `vector` without the `names`.  Get the index and then loop through the index to change the type

```
i1 <- grepl("cm|mmHg", names(data))
data[i1] <- lapply(data[i1], as.numeric)
```

---

But, this can be done automatically with `type.convert` (given the columns are all `character` class - here it is `character`)

```
data[] <- lapply(data, type.convert, as.is = TRUE)
```

---

Or using `mutate_if`

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
   mutate_if(i1, as.numeric)
```

Or from the comments (@kath, @FlorianGD), `mutate_at` with `matches` to select the columns of interest and apply the function

```
data %>% 
   mutate_at(vars(matches("cm|mmHg")), as.numeric)
```

Comment: thanks. I didn't realise the vector name wasn't passed. OK type.convert is new to me. Thanks again

Comment: @SebastianZeki `data[i1] <-` will insert the "new" data supplied as `list` into the old `structure`. That's very useful when you want to change "column content" but not the overall form.

Comment: Using dplyr, I think you could use `mutate_at` to do it in one go

Comment: @FlorianGD  Yes, it needs a `names` or numeric index `data %>% mutate_at(which(i1), as.numeric)`

Comment: What about `mutate_at(data, vars(matches("cm|mmHg")), as.numeric)`, then you have it in one go ;)

Comment: Can you mix mutate_at with something like `vars(starts_with("cm|
mmHg"))`? Maybe it's be becoming less readable

Comment: @FlorianGD  The `matches` in `ends_with` or `starts_with` take a fixed string, so the `|` would not work as expected